# Operands for operator equal does not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have below method -

```
public void SaveNotification()
{
   if(ARequest==null) return;

   IList<Notification> lstNotification = objDataAccess.GetNotification(_userInfo.UserId);
   
   if(lstNotification?.Count>0)
   {
    foreach(Notification objNotification in lstNotification)
    {
      notificationRepository.Insert(objNotification);
    }
    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

On savechanges of db context , I am getting -

```
Operands for operator equal does not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'
```

I am not getting idea at which point in this code I am checking for equality to save.

I am using .NETCore 2.1.1 + OracleEntityframework Core 2.19

Comment: Did you override `SaveChanges` method and if yes, can we see the code. Also the `Notification` class. Also the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old issue on the EFCore. If you are using == or != operands in this process use Equals instead.
Try the below code, also it may be in the implementation of the `GetNotification` method that you use the == or != operands.

```
public void SaveNotification()
{
   if(ARequest.Equals(null)) return;

   IList<Notification> lstNotification = objDataAccess.GetNotification(_userInfo.UserId);
   
   if(lstNotification?.Count>0)
   {
    foreach(Notification objNotification in lstNotification)
    {
      notificationRepository.Insert(objNotification);
    }
    _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

reference of issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11248

Comment: holdup.. what's an old issue on the EfCore? How does this solve the problem... What is the problem?

Comment: @TheGeneral check this link https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11248

Comment: Great, you might want to add that to the answer as a reference

Comment: @TheGeneral I added it to the answer, thanks

Comment: Other than the error message itself, I don't see how this relates to OP issue - *"On savechanges of db context , I am getting..."* If that's true, `SaveChanges`, (if not overridden) is out of user control and cannot be fixed. Also the error message is about runtime expression, so it cannot be caused by compile time check `if(ARequest==null)`, hence the proposed `Equals` won't solve anything.